# Filter out namespaces xml in Spark Scala

Tags: regex, parsing, apache-spark, filter, spark-streaming

I am trying to filter the namespace information out of an xml being read in by spark streaming. Below is a sample xml. This is the code I am trying. It should filter out all "ns:0", "ns:1"... from the xml. The xml will be read in as rdd because of spark streaming.

```
val message_filter = message.filter(x => x.matches("([n][s][0-9]:)+")))

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Period>
  <AllContacts>
    <Entry>
      <ns0:entity-Person>
        <ns0:CellPhone>3095550101</ns0:CellPhone>
        <ns0:FirstName>Brrzzz</ns0:FirstName>
        <ns0:LastName>Grbbs</ns0:LastName>
      </ns0:entity-Person>
      <ns0:PrimaryPhone>mobile</ns0:PrimaryPhone>
    </Entry>
  </AllContacts>
  <State>TX</State>
</Period>
```

Desired Format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Period>
  <AllContacts>
    <Entry>
      <entity-Person>
        <CellPhone>3095550101</CellPhone>
        <FirstName>Brrzzz</FirstName>
        <LastName>Grbbs</LastName>
      </entity-Person>
      <PrimaryPhone>mobile</PrimaryPhone>
    </Entry>
  </AllContacts>
  <State>TX</State>
</Period>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, `x.matches` accepts regular expressions, than your regex should look something like this:`/ns\d+:([\w-]+)/g`  here is the example at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rW7tT7/2)